# How to optimize app size in Corona SDK?

Tags: android, ios, video, size, coronasdk

I'm trying to make a cross platform app (iOS & Android). The app includes several video files. In general the app have no difficult functionality, but the size is about 40 Mb (14 Mb pictures and 16 Mb videos).

By the app scenario you should choose the hero in first run: Male of Female. After that the 1st video plays - a hero come to some office and manager meet him (there are 2 videos - 1 for male hero and 1 for female).

When 1st video ended (or was skipped by tap) button "Get something" appears. If you tap this button 2nd video starts - manager go away from office and come back with some goods.

After that the hero gets the goods and go away (two videos for male and female hero).

I decided to use video, because I need visualize hero's actions maximality.

**1. I need to optimize the app size by using something else instead video. Any advice?**

**2. Why my app frequently crashes on Android device but work quite stable on iOS devices?**

Thanks for any advice. Sorry for my english. :)

Comment: Why you need to use video. You have to explain it. The someone can advise you.

Answer (score 0):

Videos are heavy, if you can reduce the amount of videos used by your game.

- To optimize video space: Use smaller video resolutions, use less videos
- To optimize image space: Create a spritesheet with all the images in it (see http://www.codeandweb.com/texturepacker)

Cheers!